# First few coefficients of a power series

Tags: calculus, power-series

The function $f(x) =\frac{5}{1+16x^2}$ is represented by the power series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nx^n$$

I'm supposed to find the first few coefficients of the power series, and these are the answers that I got:
$c_0 = 5$
$c_1 = -80$
$c_2 = 1280$
$c_3 = -20,480$
$c_4 = 327,680$

Yet the WebWork system is saying that $c_1$ through $c_4$ is incorrect.

I've been using this method to find the $n^{th}$ coeffecient:
$$\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}$$

where $c$ the center of the series is $0$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See, for example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355158/generating-functions-closed-form-of-a-sequence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: What you wrote are the first five *nonzero* coefficients.

Comment: @Jordan:   Which you calculated correctly.  You did some extra work, though.

Comment: Ah I see. That's very helpful. How do I get all coefficients, including zeroes? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Never mind. After hours of figuring this out it finally came to me :) thank you for your help.

Comment: @Jordan You're welcome -- the fact is that the several hours of thinking about it is what makes you remember how to do it in the future.