# inverse z-transform $E(z)=\frac{z}{(z-2)(z-1)^2}$

Tags: partial-fractions, z-transform

The question is:
Find the inverse z-transform of $E(z)=\frac{z}{(z-2)(z-1)^2}$

so far I have:
using partial fractions with repeating factors...
$$\frac{z}{(z-2)(z-1)^2}=\frac{Az}{(z-2)}+\frac{Bz}{(z-1)}+\frac{Cz}{(z-1)^2}\\
z=Az(z-1)^2+Bz(z-2)(z-1)^2+Cz(z-2)$$

z=1: $$1=A1(1-1)^2+B(1(1-2)(1-1)^2+C1(1-2)^2\\
1=0+0+C(-1)^2\\
1=-C\\
C=-1$$

setting z=2 results in:
$$A=1$$

How do I go about solving B?

$$E(z)=\frac{z}{z-2}+\frac{Bz}{z-1}-\frac{z}{(z-2)^2}$$
taking the inverse z-transform then...
$$e(k)=2^k+???+\frac{1}{2}k2^k$$

Please tell me this is remotely correct. If not, please show me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Try getting rid of $z$ in the nominator, i.e. $$\frac{z}{(z-2)(z-1)^2}=\frac{A}{(z-2)}+\frac{B}{(z-1)}+\frac{C}{(z-1)^2}$$ and go from there.

Comment: How can we just get rid of the z? Do we not have to multiply it into the other side then?

Comment: See my answer below. On another note: it's not a good idea to plug in values for $z$. The equation must _generally hold_, not just for specific values of $z$.

Comment: You are on the right track: The answer is: $f(n) = 2^n-n-1$

Comment: A [related technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279868/causal-inverse-z-transform-of-fibonacci).

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that $\frac{z}{(z-2)(z-1)^2}=\frac{Az}{(z-2)}+\frac{Bz}{(z-1)}+\frac{Cz}{(z-1)^2}$ is wrong. It should be:
$$\frac{z}{(z-2)(z-1)^2}=\frac{A}{(z-2)}+\frac{B}{(z-1)}+\frac{C}{(z-1)^2}$$

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Procedure) for examples why.

Now, multiply by the denominator on the left hand side to get
$$z=A(z-1)^2+B(z-2)(z-1)+C(z-2) \implies\\
(A+B)z^2-(1+2A+3B+C)z+A+2B-2C=0$$

For this equation to generally hold, the coefficients of each of the powers of $z$ must be equal on both sides (the coefficients on the right hand side is of course zero). This leads to the following equation system.

$$\begin{cases}
A+B=0\\1+2A+3B-C=0\\A+2B-2C=0\\
\end{cases}
$$
Now solve it, and plug in the resulting $A$, $B$ and $C$ above and apply the inverse z-transform on the terms.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using partial fractions method use residue method or convolution theorem: they are very easy and you can get the answer without any confusion. I'm attaching residue method photo once refer to it!

At last for $z=1$ you'll get $-n-1$ as answer. Then add two residues i.e., $ 2^n-n-1$ is the answer! Likewise you can get anything through this method if you find difficulty in writing partial fractions.

[image: photo]