# Find the inverse z-transform of $E(z)=\frac{z+1}{(z-1)(z-0.6)}$

Tags: inverse, partial-fractions, z-transform

$$\begin{align}
E(z)&=\frac{z+1}{(z-1)(z-0.6)}\\
\frac{z+1}{(z-1)(z-0.6)}&=\frac{A}{(z-1)}+\frac{B}{(z-0.6)}\\
z+1&=A(z-0.6)+B(z-1)
\end{align}$$

set z=0.6:
$$\begin{align}
0.6+1&=A(0)+B(0.6-1)\\
1.6&=B(-0.4)\\
B&=\frac{1.6}{-0.4}\\
&=-4
\end{align}$$
set z=1:
$$\begin{align}
1+1&=A(1-0.6)+B(0)\\
2&=A(0.4)\\
A&=\frac{2}{0.4}\\
&=5
\end{align}$$
So
$$E(z)=\frac{5}{(z-1)}-\frac{4}{(z-0.6)}$$
Please explain to me how we go from that to:
$$e(k)=\delta(k-1)(5-4(0.6)^k)$$

How do I use the z-transform tables such as the one found on page 4 of [this PDF](http://mosaic.cnfolio.com/ParchizadehB307Files/files.xml?action=download&file=5.The_Z_transform_techniques.pdf) to solve this problem?

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279868/causal-inverse-z-transform-of-fibonacci).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the table, you will need to use the fact that a multiplication with $z^{-1}$ corresponds to a time shift with $-1$ in the time domain. More generally:

$$z^{-k}X(z) \leftrightarrow x[n-k]$$

The first term in $E(z)$ can be written as 
$$5z^{-1}\frac{z}{z-1}$$

Using time shifting and the first entry in the table gives us that
$$5z^{-1}\frac{z}{z-1} \leftrightarrow5u[n-1]$$

The second term can similarly be written as $$4z^{-1}\frac{z}{z-0.6}$$

According to the fourth row in the table 
$$\frac{z}{z-e^{-aT}} \leftrightarrow e^{-at}, \;t>0$$

Now, remember that T is the time corresponding to one sample. The continuous time $t$ can thus be written $t=nT$, and the transform pair can then be expressed using only $n$ as follows:

$$\frac{z}{z-e^{-\alpha}} \leftrightarrow e^{-\alpha n}$$

and, since this is valid for $t>0$ (causality), the right-hand side can be written $e^{-\alpha n}u[n]$.

In this case, $e^{-\alpha} = 0.6$ and this together with the time scaling property gives
$$4z^{-1}\frac{z}{z-0.6} \leftrightarrow 4(0.6)^{n-1}u[n-1] = \frac{20}3(0.6)^nu[n-1] $$

Now we can put together the resulting inverse z transform:

$$e[n] = 5u[n-1] - \frac{20}3(0.6)^nu[n-1]=u[n-1]\left(5-\frac{20}3(0.6)^n\right)$$

I don't know where you get $e(k)=\delta(k-1)(5-4(0.6)^k)$ from, but it can't be right, can it?