# Problem with understanding generating functions.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I am given generating functions $f(x)= \frac{x}{1-x}$ or $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$ or $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-5x+6}$ and I am obliged to write sequence which are generated by this functions. What is the fastest algorithm to solve these problems? I have problem with even starting. I will be glad if anyone would be so nice to explain me algorithm to solve this kind of exercises or post any reference that is related with my problem.

Comment: You just need to know the formula for a geometric series: $\sum_{n \geq 0} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$.  In the second one, replace $x$ with $-x^2$, i.e., $\frac{1}{1 + x^2} = \frac{1}{1 - (-x^2)}$.  For the last, factor and then use partial fractions.

Comment: $\large{\frac{1}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{1}{x-3}-\frac{1}{x-2}=\frac{-1/3}{1-(x/3)}- \frac{-1/2}{1-(x/2)}} $

Comment: @SpamIAm So for $\sum_{n \geq 0} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$ I got the sequence $a_{n}=1$ ?

Comment: experiment with Taylor series, with a "robot" like [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+2%E2%88%9A%28t%2F%28t-1%29%29arctan%28%E2%88%9A%28t%2F%28t-1%29%29%29 ]

Comment: @MarcinMajewski Yes, that's right, just as Alex stated in his answer below.

Comment: @K.Rmth So I find formula for sequence $\large\frac{-1/3}{1-(x/3)}$ and for $\frac{-1/2}{1-(x/2)}$ and then subtract this formulas and I am done?

Comment: @MarcinMajewski Yes, resulting in ${\large{\frac{1}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{1}{x-3}-\frac{1}{x-2}=\frac{-1/3}{1-(x/3)}- \frac{-1/2}{1-(x/2)}}}={-1\over 3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ({x\over 3})^n+{1\over 2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ({x\over 2})^n$

Answer (score 2):

By the fundamental theorem of algebra, any real-valued polynomial can be factorised into real quadratics. Sometimes these quadratics can be factored further into linear binomials, and if not they are writeableas a sum of two squares.

Given a  ratio of polynomials, $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ (where we take the degree of $p$ to be less; if that is not the case then we can use polynomial division to make it the case), we can factor $q(x)$ into a product of linear terms and quadratics which are the sum of two squares. For now we assume the roots of $q$ are distinct, but the case of multiple roots can be dealt with.

We can then use partial fraction decomposition to write this as a sum of constants over linear terms, and linear terms over quadratic terms. These can be expressed as series using the geometric series expansion, viz:
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^{2} +\ldots; \quad \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}=\frac{1}{1-(-x^{2})}=1-x^{2}+x^{4}-\ldots$$

With generating functions, we are looking to find the coefficient on $x^{n}$, which the method I've described above allows us to do. If you're unfamiliar with any of these techniques, let me know in a comment.

Comment: I understand what you try to explain me. But I am somehow confused. $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^{2} +\ldots;$ You write this but the task was to find a sequence for example : $a_{n}=\frac{-1}{3^{n}}$ How to achive that? I am not familiar with this method. How to find this coefficient of $x^{n}$ ? I will be glad if you could elaborate and help me on this topic.

Comment: Are you saying you want to find a generating function which generates $a_{n}=\frac{-1}{3^{n}}$? That would just be a geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x}{1-x}=x\frac{1}{1-x}=x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n}$$
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{1-(-x^2)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-x^2)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n}$$

Comment: So when I get $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n}$ the sequence will be $a_{n}=1^{n}$ ? How to interpretate this?

Comment: No, the sequence is $(1,1, \ldots)$, not $1^n$.

Comment: @Alex Ok I got this. And for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n}$ the sequence is $a_{n}=(-1)^{n}$ ?

Comment: No, the sequnce is $(1,-1,1,\ldots)$

Comment: @Alex This is what I meant but I wrote formula for this sequence

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\frac{1}{1-x}=(1-x)^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 1 \cdot x^k$, so the sequence this GF generates is $<1,1, \ldots>$

EDIT: 'in general' you need to represent the GF in the form $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k$, and $\{ a_k \}$ is the sequence that this GF generates.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For ordinary generating function, you need to find the coefficient of $x^n$, so you need to find the power series expansion of these functions. See this [technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279868/causal-inverse-z-transform-of-fibonacci).

Answer (score 0):

In general given the ratio of two polynomials, apply partial fraction decomposition to the ratio so as to obtain a sum of terms that can be expanded as a binomial series, then collect the coefficients.