# Initial values are lost (diff eq to Transfer function)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, laplace-transform

I read eternal [Julius O. Smith III](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Z_Transform_Difference_Equations.html) and he says that

[$$x_{n-m} = z^{-m}X(z)$$](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Shift_Theorem.html)

Particularly, difference relation

$$y_{n} = y_{n-1} + x_{n}$$

is solved by by

$$Y = z^{-1}Y + X = {X \over (1-z^{-1})}$$

Applied impulse function $x[n] = [1,0,0,0,0,0]$ so that $ X = 1 + 0 z^{-1} + 0 z ^{-2} + \ldots = 1$, we can get the impulse response $Y = 1/(1-z^{-1}) = 1 + z^{-1} + z^{-2} + \ldots.$ This seems right. However, my generating functions and [Laplace method](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IVPWithLaplace.aspx) (see how y'' is translated into $s^2Y$-sy(0) - y'(0)) suggest that we

$$y_1 + y_2 z^{-1}  + y_3 z^{-2} + \ldots = z (y_1 z^{-1}  + y_2 z^{-2} + \dots) = z^{-1} (y_0 + y_1 z^{-1}  + y_2 z^{-2} + \dots - y_0) = z (Y - y_0)$$

and recurrence is translated into

$$z( Y - y_0) = Y + z(X -x_0)$$

whereupon

$$Y = z^{-1}Y + X -x_0 + y_0 = {X + y_0 - x_0 \over 1-z^{-1}} $$

I do not know what to do with $x_0$. It seems be able to conflict with definition of X or duplicate it. I mean that X already contains $x_0$. What does it mean? Anyway, is Julius Smith III right that we can solve the difference equations this way? Why should we ignore $y_0$?

Comment: You question starts with difference equations and ends with differential equations? How did you come up with the equation after "suggest that we"?

Comment: @copper.hat What is the difference? I read that Z-transform is a counterpart of Laplace transform. Do you mean that unlike Laplace transform, z does not have any initial values? Do you give a hint to answer that way? What is the point of your comment?

Comment: There is a similarity between the z-transform and the Laplace transform. But I have no idea how you leaped to the $y_1+y_2 z^{-1}+...$ formula above.

Comment: @copper.hat You may read a book or point me to the error that I made (if that is your point). I do not prohibit users to follow the links that I have posted.

Comment: Val. I am fairly familiar with both z- and Laplace-transforms. You start by asking a question about a difference equation/z-transform of shifted sequence (which you have transcribed incorrectly) and then leap to another difference equation which you have pulled from nowhere. I am aware that I may read a book thanks. And I did point out the source of confusion. Your ball.

Comment: @copper.hat $y_n = y_{n-1} + x_n$ is the same as $y_{n+1} = y_{n} + x_{n+1}.$

Comment: This is becoming a bit silly. I understand that you can change variables. You have an equation above $y_1+y_2 z^{-1}+...$. I have no idea where you pulled this from.

Comment: @copper.hat This is generating functions approach. The relation $y_i = y_{i-i}$ is translated into a series of equations $\begin{bmatrix}y_1 = y_0 \\ y_2 x = y_1 x \\ y_3 x^2= y_2 x^3 \\ \cdots \end{bmatrix}$ They are summed up with $y_0 + y_1 x + y_2 x^2 + \ldots = Y(x)$. The right hand is Y(x) already. The left part is started with $y_1$.

Comment: I am afraid you have lost me. You have $y_1 + y_2 z^{-1}  + y_3 z^{-2} = z (Y - y_0)$ above. Where did $y_4 z^{-4}$ etc, go????? And where are you getting $y_i = y_{i-1}$ from?

Comment: @copper.hat Where do you see no ldots?

Comment: Please read my first comment.

Comment: @copper.hat You say that I confuse difference with differential then say that I have leaped from one difference eq to another difference eq and you do not get where $y_1 + y_2 z^{-1}+\ldots$ comes from then you say that I have ommited ellipsis somewhere then you say that I must start over with difference confused with differential. This looks like a circle without logical connections between the nodes. Furthermore, I started with difference equation and ended up with that. The reference to Paul Notes with Laplace transform was just to say that Laplace method does not discard the initial vals.

Comment: You asked where I see no ldots. The first equation after "suggest that we".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are asking two questions. The first is about an apparent issue because you are not using the fact that $y_0 = y_{-1} + x_0$. The second is if you can solve difference equations using the z-transform.

A few comments first:

My discussion ignores issues of convergence and existence of the z-transform. I assume that the relevant transforms are defined on $|z|>R$ for some $R$.

Given a sequence $x: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$, the unilateral z-transform of $x$ is given by $\hat{x}(z) =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n z^{-1}$. 
A sequence is called causal **iff** $x_n = 0$ for all $n <0$.

Define the right-shift $(Rx)_n = x_{n-1}$. Note that $(Rx)_0 = x_{-1}$. Then we have $\widehat{Rx} (z) = x_{-1}+ z^{-1}  \hat{x}(z)$.
If $x$ is causal (in fact, if $x_{-1} = 0$), then $(Rx)_0 = 0$ and $\widehat{Rx} (z) = z^{-1} \hat{x}(z)$.

If $x$ is causal, then it should be clear that $\widehat{R^kx} (z) = z^{-k} \hat{x}(z)$, where $R^k$ is $R\circ \cdots \circ R$ (that is, $k$ times).

Define the left-shift $(Lx)_n = x_{n+1}$. Note that if $x$ is causal , then $Lx$ is not necessarily causal because we have $(Lx)_{-1} = x_0$. In this case, we have $\widehat{Lx} (z) = z (\hat{x}(z)-x_0)$.

The point is that with causal sequences and the unilateral z-transform, a right shift corresponds to multiplication by $z^{-1}$, but a left shift needs to be modified slightly before multiplying by $z$.

Now for the first issue:

In the question above, the equation is $y_n = y_{n-1}+x_n$. Note that this can be written as $y_n = (Ry)_n + x_n$ or more succinctly as $y = Ry+x$.
Furthermore, setting $n=0$ gives $y_0 = y_{-1} + x_0$.

Taking the transform gives $\hat{y}(z) = y_{-1} + z^{-1} \hat{y}(z) + \hat{x}(z)$. This gives $\hat{y}(z) = {y_{-1}+\hat{x}(z) \over 1- z^{-1}}$.
If $y$ is causal, then $y_{-1} = 0$ and the formula simplifies to the formula above, that is, $\hat{y}(z) = {\hat{x}(z) \over 1- z^{-1}}$. So far, so good.

If I understand what it is that you did above (after the phrase "suggest that we"), you consider the equivalent equation $y_{n+1} = y_n + x_{n+1}$, which can be written as $Ly = y+Lx$. Taking transforms gives
$z ( \hat{y}(z)-y_0) = \hat{y}(z) + z ( \hat{x}(z)-x_0)$, dividing across by $z$ gives $\hat{y}(z)-y_0 = z^{-1} \hat{y}(z) + \hat{x}(z)-x_0$, which simplifies to $\hat{y}(z) = {y_{0}-x_0+\hat{x}(z) \over 1- z^{-1}}$.

Since $y_0 = y_{-1} + x_0$, the two equations are equal.

Now the second question:

If two different sequences $x,y$ satisfy $x_n = y_n $ for all $n \ge 0$ then we have $\hat{x} = \hat{y}$, that is, the unilateral z-transform only 'cares' about the values of $x$ when $n \ge 0$. Hence if we use this transform to solve difference equations, at best it will tell us about solution behaviour for $n \ge 0$.

If $x,y$ are causal and $\hat{x} = \hat{y}$, then we have $x=y$. This is what allows us to find a solution to a difference equation.

Suppose you have a difference equation of the form (taken from the notes you referred to)
$y_n = \sum_{k=0}^M b_k x_{n-k} - \sum_{k=0}^N a_k y_{n-k}$, and both $x,y$ are causal. Then this can be written as
$y =\sum_{k=0}^M b_k R^k x - \sum_{k=0}^N a_k R^k y$, and taking transforms yields
$\hat{y}(z) = \sum_{k=0}^M b_k z^{-k} \hat{x}(z) - \sum_{k=0}^N a_k z^{-k} \hat{y}(z)$, or equivalently,
$\hat{y}(z) = \hat{h}(z) \hat{x}(z)$, where
$\hat{h}(z) = { \sum_{k=0}^M b_k z^{-k} \over 1+\sum_{k=0}^N a_k z^{-k}}$.

Hence if one is given a suitable causal $x$, then to solve the equation  one computes $\hat{x}$, multiplies it (pointwise) by $\hat{h}$ to get $\hat{y}$ and then computes the sequence that $y$ that corresponds to $\hat{y}$. Then this will be the unique causal solution to the difference equation.

Comment: Where did I declare something to be obvious???

Comment: It seems that shifting both left and right we can have equations with all initial values = 0! That is brilliant! Also, when I Z-transform $R[x_0, x_1, \ldots] = [0, x_0, x_1, \ldots]$, I'll get $0 + x_0 z^{-1}+ x_1 z^{-2} + \ldots = z^{-1} \sum_0^\infty{x_n z^{-n}} = z^{-1} X(z)$ -- no initial value whereas $L[x_0, x_1, \ldots] = [x_0 | x_1, x_2, \ldots]$ is encoded by $x_1 + x_2 z^{-1} + x_3z^{-2} + \ldots = z(x_0 + x_1z^{-1}+x_2z^{-2} + \ldots - x_0) = z(X(z) - x_0)$. You see how naturally Z-transform itself points us when initial values are necessary and when they must be abridged.

Comment: I meant to say `shift left and right sides of the equation`. Now, I see that even non-casual systems, i.e. when $y_n = b_{n+1}$, that is when y depends on data from the future, and, thus $b_0$ is important, $Y(z)=z(B(z)-b_0)$. Yet, if we right-shift both sides of equation, $y_{n-1} = b_n$, aka multiply Z-transfrom by $z^{-1}$, we'll get rid of $b_0$: $z^{-1}Y(z) = B(z)$. Does that mean that $b_0$ = 0? That is interesting.

Comment: Wait, this means that $y_{n+1} = y_n$ is a series of all zeroes. It is because $y_0 = y_{n-1} = 0$ then $y_1 = y_0 = 0$ and so on. All $y_n$ are zero in this case. This eliminates the possibility to have anything else in the sequence. Particularly, fibonacci sequence y_1 and y_0 must be zeroes because they must conform $y_n = y_{n-1} + y_{n-2}.$ I see that I can introduce non-zeroes by adding something to $y_n$, e.g. $y_n = y_{n-1} + b_n.$ How do you do that for Fibbonacci or it is non-casual?

Comment: I have asked latter [in another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883552). I have also discovered that there is a way to make the Fibbonacci casual, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279868 -- we need to add a delta-pulse: $y_n = y_{n-1} + y_{n-2} +\delta$