# Causal non-causal sequences

Tags: signal-processing, z-transform

[This answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/10210/4701) says that $Y = zX$ is a simplest example of non-causal system because it corresponds to $y_n = x_{n+1}$ and current output depends on future input. Yet, it is causal because both [$x_n$ and $y_n$ are 0 for $n < 0.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/881232/39930) How causal can be non-causal? I am struggling to resolve this absurd and want to ask about the relationship between these two notions of causality and also the [3rd one](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Existence_Z_Transform.html), which seems to be related to pole values and ROC rather than number of poles?

Answer (score 3):

First, we can speak of a *causal filter* or a *causal function* (or *sequence*, or *signal*).

In general, a **filter** is *causal* if its output at present time ($n$) never depends on the input at future times ($n+m$, with $m>0$). Let us restrict to  LTI filters (and we assume discrete time) - so that the filter is fully specified by an impulse response function $h(n)$.
In that case, the above property can be concisely stated as follows:

- A LTI discrete-time **filter** is **causal** iff $h(n)=0$ for $n<0$

This motivates the definition of a *causal signal*.

- A discrete-time **function** (**signal**, **sequence**) $g(n)$ is **causal** iff $g(n)=0$ for $n<0$

Notice that this later definition does not involve filters (it's just motivated by them). And notice that the two can be combined in:

- A LTI discrete-time filter is causal iff its response function $h(n)$ is a causal function.

In your assertion regarding the second link ("it is causal because both $x_n$ and $y_n$ are $0$ for $n<0$") you seem to be confusing both meanings. To determine that a filter is causal, one does not look for the causality of inputs or ouputs ($x_n$ and $y_n$) but for the causality of the response function $h_n$

Further, instead of $h(n)$ we can work with its Z-transform $H(z)$; we have $y[n] = x[n] \star h[n] \implies Y(z)=H(z) \, X(z)$. But, remember the relation "signal" $\leftrightarrow$ "Z transform" is not one-to-one unless the ROC (region of convergence) is also specified. A single $H(z)$ can have several corresponding $h[n]$("anti-transform"), for different ROCs. Alternatively, instead of giving a ROC, we might be given a causal (or anticausal) condition. In particular, if we are given a (rational) $H(z)$ and we are told that $h(n)$ is causal, then the ROC must extend outwards from the biggest pole. For an explanation of this, see any Signal Processing textbook, or [here](http://cnx.org/content/m28418/1.1/).

In your example, $Y(z)= z X(z)$, so $H(z)=z$. To analyze this you can reason in two ways:

1) In terms of zeros and poles. $H(z)$ has a zero at $z=0$ and a pole at infinity. Hence, because there is a single ROC (all the plane), and it extends inwards from the pole, hence there can be only one valid $h(n)$ which must be anti-causal.

(I insist: here you could deduce from $H(z)$ that the filter was anti-causal;  but normally you can't; say, if $H(z)=z/(z-1)$ you'd have two possible $h[n]$, one causal, one anticausal).

2) Explicitly, formally. By inspection, $H(z)=\sum_{n} h(n) z^{-n} = z \implies h(n)=\delta(n+1)$ Which is anticausal.

Comment: Thanks. I just did not get how the non-causal Y = zX is causal, how reading data from the future is reconciled with being causal filters/signals?

Comment: Y = zX is _not_ causal

Comment: Really? Do you understand my question? Or you are saying that there is a principal difference between not and non in English?

Comment: I just don't understand why you insist on saying "$Y = zX$ is causal". That's false.

Comment: @leonboy It is explained several times. At first in the referenced answer and then repeated in the first sentence of my question. I can say once more that Y = zX corresponds to $y_n = x_{n+1}$, which means that you compute current output based on the future input, which means non-casualty. But, I see no reason why you will notice this after one more repetition.

Comment: "I see no reason why you will notice this after one more repetition"  Sorry, I can't parse that.